# gtv-ui-lib jquery: long list navigation failure?

Tags: jquery, google-tv

Do the [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/gtv-ui-lib/) supplied by Google for supporting D-pad navigation within HTML5 handle long lists?

Looking for examples, I came across a page at Khan Academy that uses the jquery flavor of the libraries:

http://www.khanacademy.org/gtv/

When viewing that page on Google TV, I see a problem navigating down the list with the D-pad down-arrow key. Navigation just stops at a certain cell (Algebra:Logarithms), refusing to go further down.

What could be the problem?  The source code looks fine--there isn't much besides the library code--as it creates well-formed DIV tags to make up the long list.  I tried copying files locally and replacing the libraries with the most recently published copy (from 2/2011)--no change.

The bug is [described](http://code.google.com/p/khanacademy/issues/detail?id=9881) on the Khan issues site, along with [another](http://code.google.com/p/khanacademy/issues/detail?id=9883), and as a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=29) for GTV now too.

Comment: Could you file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug with Template Javascript file due to a hardcoded parameter rowsPerPage in index.js file. Please see the following issue for more detail.

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=29

Once you increase this number to something like 100, it can accommodate long list like what Khan app has i.e. 49 items.